# Getting list of class methods

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm looking for a way to get a static methods list for a certain class. I only get  a list of instance methods with the runtime function `class_copyMethodList()`.

Is there a way to list static methods?

Comment: You mean a list of class methods? How about checking an every method using class_getClassMethod function with the method list from class_copyMethodList function?

Comment: Thanks for response. But with class_copyMethodList I get only instance methods, static methods (defined with +) are not included.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Each `Class` is itself an Objective-C object, and in turn has an object which is (sort of) its class. You need to get this [metaclass object](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html) (see also: ["[objc explain]: Classes and Metaclasses"](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html)), and then ask that for its methods (which will be the class methods* you are after).

From the [`class_copyMethodList`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418490-class_copymethodlist?language=objc) docs:

> ###Discussion
> To get the class methods of a class, use `class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(cls), &count)`

---

*There's [no such thing as static methods in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089186/objective-c-difference-between-class-method-and-static-method/8089623#8089623).