# Is there an official name for the + and - symbols before ObjC method declarations?

Tags: objective-c, terminology

Do the `+` or `-` symbols at the beginning of a method's declaration -- for class and instance methods respectively -- have a name?

By name I mean something like "method descriptor" or "method type indicator", or something similar.

Comment: Could you give us an idea of the context you're looking to use it in?  I would normally refer to them directly as 'class methods' or 'instance methods'.

Comment: I am asking specifically about the + or - sign from the perspective of objC language. Those are mathematical characters used in a very specific context. Does objC call them somehow?
I am contemplating this on the same level of abstraction as words like "method signature", "selector", "keyword", "preprocessor directive"...etc..

Is there such a word that describes those two signs in objc specific context?

Comment: I've never seen a name for the actual +/- characters.  Likely there is something in the compiler's source code, but there's never been a great need to expose it.

Comment: If I had to come up with a term, I'd probably call them something like 'method type indicators'.  Alternatively (and arguably preferably), you could consider them to be part of the method signature.

Comment: I've never heard an official name, but i tend to think of `+` as denoting a `static` method, vs an instance method.

Comment: [Not static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8089623/), @Nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [Hot Licks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142910/is-there-a-proper-official-name-for-methods-type-indicator-on-objective-c#comment44657539_28142910); I've never seen a name for these tokens in any documentation, and [the relevant part of Clang's parser](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Parse/ParseObjc.cpp#L642)

```
Decl *Parser::ParseObjCMethodPrototype(tok::ObjCKeywordKind MethodImplKind,
                                       bool MethodDefinition) {
  assert((Tok.is(tok::minus) || Tok.is(tok::plus)) && "expected +/-");
```

just calls them "plus" and "minus". (See also [ParseObjc.cpp line 322](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Parse/ParseObjc.cpp#L322); the same.)

"Method type indicator" sounds pretty reasonable to me, though, if you really need something. I personally would easily understand what you were talking about.