# In iOS, if UILabel inherits from UIView then why isn't the animate method available to UILabel?

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

In iOS, if UILabel inherits from UIView then why isn't the animate method available to UILabel and how would I have known to go up the class?  I know its probably private to the UIView class but wouldn't it make sense to have it directly available to UILabel as well?  How does Apple or developers dictate what methods should or should not be available?

Here's an example:

```
func animateLabelTransitions(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.5, animations: {self.questionLabel.alpha = 1})
    }
```

Comment: your label.alpha is 0 before the animate block?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes, its set to 0 in viewWillAppear.

Comment: I don´t understand quite well your question you are saying that .alpha property of a label can´t be animated?

Comment: @ReinierMelian well this code works but what I'm trying to say or ask is, why wouldn't developers make the animate method accessible to UILabel directly if UILabel inherits from UIView anyway?

Comment: The animate method has no 'receiver' there is no instance of a anything receiving the function, its a class method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`animate` is a class method, not an instance method; it applies to all views simultaneously, not some specific view. There's no need to specify which one thing you're trying to animate. You can put many things in the block and animate them all together. What would you expect to happen if you called `UILabel.animate(...)` and animated a button inside of the block? That would be totally legal (since it would just call the `UIView` version which can animate anything), but very confusing.

Comment: nice answer! +1

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks!  Can I ask how do you know its a static method because when I look at the reference docs online, the animate function is prefixed with the word 'class'.  For example on this Apple reference doc for an animate function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate

Comment: Yes; class method. There isn't a strong distinction in ObjC.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm going to vote you as the best answer since the GUI placed you at the top for being the first I'm guessing.  If you can, could you elaborate on your opinion as to why there isn't a strong distinction between static and class methods in ObjC?

Comment: ObjC doesn't have static methods at all; it only has class methods. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089186/whats-the-difference-between-class-method-and-static-method/8089623#8089623 for a good overview. But also notice the wildly divergent terms and meanings ObjC devs use in the comments and answers. bbum is certainly correct (he usually is on most topics), but the muddling of the terms is very common in the Cocoa world. I didn't mean to confuse you here.

Answer (score 3):

The `animate` methods are available to `UILabel`. They are class methods of `UIView` which means they are class methods of any subclass of `UIView` as well.

While pointless, you could have written your code as:

```
func animateLabelTransitions(){
    UILabel.animate(withDuration: 3.5, animations {
        self.questionLabel.alpha = 1
    })
}
```

But what's the point? This would confuse a lot of people. Just call the `animate` methods on `UIView`.

Just because you call `animate` on `UIView` doesn't mean it restricts what you can put inside the animation or completion blocks.

Comment: seems legit.  If I were an Apple developer, I would just have a fear that since its a class method then it would affect all UIViews.  Is this code visible to us the community to see how Apple put this method together?  If this is a dumb question I apologize.

Comment: It does animate all UIViews. And no, we do not have source code for it (though it's not that hard to reverse engineer most of these w/ Hopper… haven't tried this one, but always educational)

Comment: @RobNapier I see, I'm guessing we directly call on which view we want to animate like I did above.  Its making more sense, can I ask is there a method where we can grab all visible UIViews in a ViewController instead of just coding up each one directly?

Comment: @Q.A.Neuro.Tech A class method means you can call it without needing a specific instance of the class. Don't confuse calling a class method with affecting all currently existing instances of that class. They have nothing to do with each other. There is nothing to fear. Calling a class method on `UIView` has no affect on any views unless that particular method happens to be written to affect clearly specified views such as the `animate` methods. Those affect only those views that you tell it to in the animation block.

Comment: OMG, I had to research on Google how to vote for the best answer just now.  You are awesome and you've improved my questions over time with your earlier suggestions on edits in which I'm highly grateful for.  You also gave me words of comfort and encouragement but the GUI placed @RobNapier answer at the top I'm guessing because he was first.  My toughest decision of the day.